# AutoML Natural Language UI don't show extracted text to annotate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

After uploading the data to google AutoML for Entity Extraction (I followed this https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare). I got this error for big files (I checked that they are not bigger than 2MB which is the maximum amount for pdf's)

> Fail to load example and annotations. Error details: Unknown error.

My items are already uploaded to a dataset on Google AutoML. When I click an item to perform the annotation for costum entities then I get the above's error.

Update: Now the error looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How many files have you uploaded?

Comment: more then 350 pdf's. Each pdf can have moren than 40 pages

Comment: I am currently having the same problem from last friday.

Comment: For GCP to ingest your PDF documents, you need to create JSONL (JSON Lines) files and a CSV to reference the JSONL data. Have you done those steps too or you need help with that?

Comment: I did those steps, I have a csv file having a jsonl uri on each line. I uploaded the data, also I received an email with Operation succeded as a result. Then, I am getting the error above when I try to click on an item to annotate it. With 1 or 2 pages documents it works fine. But with pdf's that have more then 4 pages it gets stucked